# How to fill SVG with video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I've been trying to place an embedded video into SVG element so it plays automatically on the background. I was able to fill the SVG with an image  the way I wanted using the pattern, but I can't do the same thing with the video. I'd prefer the most simple solution (such as fill:url(#image) in the example) that will do the trick. Any help?

```css
svg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
              viewBox="0 0 534 503" style="enable-background:new 0 0 534 503;" xml:space="preserve">
              <defs>
                <pattern id="image" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100%" width="100%">
                  <image x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/7Nlcay7.jpg"></image>
                </pattern>
              </defs>
              <style type="text/css">
              .st0{fill:none;enable-background:new    ;}
              .st1{fill:url(#image);stroke:#ccc;stroke-width:20;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
              </style>
              <path class="st0" d="z"/>
              <polygon class="st1" points="268,81 333,12 457,12 524,68.5 524,206 268,491 10,207 10,66 77.5,12 202,12 "/>
            </svg>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vp2fhwy7/

Answer (score 3):

You can embed a video with the *foreignobject* tag

```
<foreignObject width="853" x="0"y="0" height="480">
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <iframe width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dkiuuMfoGvM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </body>
 </foreignObject>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vp2fhwy7/1/

Comment: but I need the video to be only inside the heart

Answer (score 2):

use a `clipPath`

**svg**

   `<clipPath id="clip">
                  <polygon class="st1" points="268,81 333,12 457,12 524,68.5 524,206 268,491 10,207 10,66 77.5,12 202,12 "/>
   </clipPath>`

**html**

 `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W4PR4vNOxfE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

**css**

`iframe {
 -webkit-clip-path:url(#clip)
}`

Comment: Can you please update my Fiddle so the video stays only inside the heart?